# Clicking userform Image control freezes the control although macro continues to run

Tags: excel, vba

This is a strange one that is causing me a bit of a headache...

Using excel 2013 and Windows 10

I have a single sheet workbook that contains, in column A, a list of addresses for image files.

I have created a single userform that contains 1 Image control, 4 x commandbuttons and a textbox.

The commandbuttons are labelled 'Forward' (CommandButton 3), 'Backward'(CommandButton 2), 'Start'(CommandButton 1) and 'Stop'(CommandButton 4). When the user clicks the Start Button, a macro is triggered which displays each of the images in turn in the image box. The row number of the image is also displayed in the textbox. When the 'Backward' button is clicked, the order of the images is reversed. When the 'Forward' buttion is clicked, forward display is resumed and when the stop button is clicked, the sequence is stopped leaving the last image displayed. This works perfectly.

However, if I click on the 'Image'control, the picture freezes although the macro continues to run and the number in the textbox continues to increase or decrease as approriate. Clicking out of the control has no effect and the image continues to stay frozen until the project is stopped.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
Public D As Single

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
D = 1
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

D = -1

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Range("A1").Select

D = 1

co = 1

Loop1:

If D = 0 Then Exit Sub

If co = 39 Then co = 1
If co = 0 Then co = 38

    Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(ActiveCell.Offset(rowoffset:=co).Value)
    Me.TextBox1.Value = co
    
    DoEvents
    
    For X = 1 To 10000
    Next X
    
    co = co + 1 * D

GoTo Loop1
    


End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

D = 0

End Sub
```

I should comment that this is a test project for a much bigger and more involved setup but it does present the same symptoms.

RannochRob

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I've no idea what causes it but, with some experimentation, I found adding the following procedure seems to solve it. Again I don't know why.

```
Private Sub Image1_Click
     Image1.visible = false
     Image1.visible = true
End sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. It worked to an extent in that the behaviour doesn't occur when the left mouse button is clicked but the right button still produces the same anomaly.   A slight modification solves the issue by using the _mouseup event. The Code then becomes Private Sub Image1_Mouseup(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

        Image1.Visible = False
        Image1.Visible = True
    
End Sub